# Install libpq-dev package error

Tags: postgresql, debian, pg

I tried to install pg gem and I have had this warning:

> You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a
>   server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side
>   application.

So I tried install libpq-dev package and I have had this warning:

> libpq-dev : Depends: libpq5 (= 8.4.17-0squeeze1) but 9.1.9-1~bpo60+1 is to be installed

How to fix this?

Comment: This same error appears when installing the node-postgres package.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This should let you install the package you need :) Just tried it myself, I am not sure you will need all the packages on the second line, try it and see :)

```
apt-get update
apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev libpam-dev libedit-dev
aptitude install -t squeeze-backports postgresql-server-dev-9.1
```

Comment: On 15.04: `sudo aptitude install postgresql-server-dev-9.4` worked. No other dependencies needed to take care of the error. This is using VirtualBox with test-kitchen and vivid server.

Comment: now i am getting aptitude: command not found.

Answer (score 27):

I have a similar problem, I solved it by installing a specific version of `libpg5`

```
sudo apt install libpq5=10.12-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
```

My machine is Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I got `E: Version '10.12-0ubuntu0.18.04.1' for 'libpq5' was not found`

Comment: This worked for me with the version listed in my error message

Comment: I think you mean `libpq5=10.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.1` (21, not 12), per https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libpq5

Comment: Note, this resulted in "The following packages will be REMOVED:
  pgadmin4 pgadmin4-desktop pgadmin4-server pgadmin4-web" for me.

Comment: I couldn't fix the problem with ***apt install***
So, I used  ***sudo aptitude install*** and downgraded version to match compatibility. It works. FYIs,

Answer (score 6):

You must setup postgresql-server-dev-X.Y, where X.Y. your's servers version, and it will install libpq-dev and other servers variables at modules for server side developing.
In my case it was

```
apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-9.5
```

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done The
>   following packages were automatically installed and are no longer
>   required:   libmysqlclient18 mysql-common Use 'apt-get autoremove' to
>   remove them. The following extra packages will be installed:
>   libpq-dev Suggested packages:   postgresql-doc-10 The following NEW
>   packages will be installed:   libpq-dev postgresql-server-dev-9.5

Comment: The strange thing: on my Rasbian `libpg-dev` can not be installed on its own. But installing `postgresql-server-dev-11` actually says, that it will install `libpg-dev`. And after that the developing library is actually installed, but `dpkg -l libpg-dev` does not show any result.

Answer (score 2):

I executed

```
apt-get -y libpq-dev
```

and it worked